# Generating zip file using c# code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to create zip file from my mvc.net c# application by using the .net framework classes.
Please response to me as soon as possible.

Comment: I'd go with one of the answers below, but just in case you work in a place where they don't like third party dlls, I'll link to my answer to a similar question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437770/how-to-extract-zip-file-using-dotnet-framework-4-0-without-using-third-party-dlls/3438147#3438147

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)?

Answer (score 3):

One third party library I've used is http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

I like it a lot more than SharpZipLib -- SharpZipLib isn't really very intuitively layed out at all.

Answer (score 3):

With **.NET 4.5** you can now create zip files really easily using the .NET framework:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
      string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
      string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

      ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

      ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code taken directly from Microsoft's documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx

There are other ways of generating compressed files that are further explained on the page linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

Use external library like [this one](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) or [this one](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).
For example with DotNetZip you can make a zip file like this:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
     // add the report into a different directory in the archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
     zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }
```