# How to extract ZIP file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compression, zip

How can I extract a ZIP file using C#?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836736/unzip-files-programmatically-in-net

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/):

> class library and toolset for manipulating zip files. Use VB, C# or any .NET language to easily create, extract, or update zip files...
>
> DotNetZip works on PCs with the full .NET Framework, and also runs on mobile devices that use the .NET Compact Framework. Create and read zip files in VB, C#, or any .NET language, or any scripting environment. DotNetZip supports these scenarios:
>
> - a Silverlight app that dynamically creates zip files.
> - an ASP.NET app that dynamically creates ZIP files and allows a browser to download them
> - a Windows Service that periodically zips up a directory for backup and archival purposes
> - a WPF program that modifies existing archives - renaming entries, removing entries from an archive, or adding new entries to an archive
> - a Windows Forms app that creates AES-encrypted zip archives for privacy of archived content.
> - a SSIS script that unzips or zips
> - An administrative script in PowerShell or VBScript that performs backup and archival.
> - a WCF service that receives a zip file as an attachment, and dynamically unpacks the zip to a stream for analysis
> - an old-school ASP (VBScript) application that produces a ZIP file via the COM interface for DotNetZIp
> - a Windows Forms app that reads or updates ODS files
> - creating zip files from stream content, saving to a stream, extracting to a stream, reading from a stream
> - creation of self-extracting archives.
>
> If all you want is a better DeflateStream or GZipStream class to replace the one that is built-into the .NET BCL, DotNetZip has that, too. DotNetZip's DeflateStream and GZipStream are available in a standalone assembly, based on a .NET port of Zlib. These streams support compression levels and deliver much better performance than the built-in classes. There is also a ZlibStream to complete the set (RFC 1950, 1951, 1952)...

have fun

Answer (score 26):

in .NET Framework 4.5 and newer

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reference: System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Comment: Is there any way to track the percentage of extraction completed?

Comment: @IneffaWolf : see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42436311/1104877

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using the #ziplib library : http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/ 
Its free and open source.

Comment: And OK license after they added the GPL exception.