# How to unzip from a stream of Embedded File in c#

Tags: c#, stream, zip, embedded-resource, unzip

I've a embedded zip file in my project. I need to unzip it to some location.

I prefer not to use external libraries.

```
    Stream _pluginZipResourceStream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("plugin.zip");
```

I tried GZipStream but ended up with errors!

```
        using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(outputFileName))
        {
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
            }
        }
```

**InvalidDataException** was unhandled: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

How to unzip it ???

Answer (score 1):

`GZip` is a specific compression algorithm, which can but most likely isn't used in your zip file.

If you're on .NET 4.5, you can use the [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx) class. If not, see [How to extract ZIP file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296918/how-to-extract-zip-file-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

If you are fortunate to use framework 4.5 or higher, you can use ZipArchive see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.IO.Compression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you are stuck with 4.0 or older, you will have to use an external library, or convert your archive to GZip.

Comment: should i use ZipArchiveEntry.ExtracttoFile ?

Comment: Depends on what you are storing in your zip file. If you have more than one file zipped there and you want to get just that one, then ZipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile ist your choice. If you just want to unzip all files, even if you have just one file there, I would prefer ZipArchive.ExtractToDirectory. Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Marking the answer as solved or at least an upvote would be a nice token of appreciation.