# Can't find ExtractToDirectory in c#

Tags: c#, unzip

I am trying to extract a zip file in C#.
I have included using `System.IO.Compression;` but when I enter `System.IO.Compression.` the only methods i see are CompressionLevel, CompressionMode, DeflateStream, and GzipStream.
`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` is not available. Is it deprecated?

Comment: Can you post your full code?  `ExtractToDirectory` is an extension of `ZipArchive` and located in the "System.IO.Compression" namespace

Comment: Did you also add a reference to the correct Assembly (`System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` as per the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21039548/27414), as the accepted answer in that question is pretty out of date.

Comment: I believe that this was only added in .Net 4 or possibly 4.5. What version are you targeting? See the "Other Versions" dropdown on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I read that it was added on version 4.5. I tried using 4.5.2 and 4.6.1. I have used the System.IO.Compression namespace

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. I am not asking how to unzip. I am asking why a specific method is not available.

Comment: @Panos - fair enough. Sorry for the itchy trigger finger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Using VS2015 and creating a console app does not add this by default.