# How to extract a folder from zip file using SharpZipLib?

Tags: c#, .net, zip, directory, compression

I have a `test.zip` file which contains inside a Folder with a bunch of other files and folders in it.

I found [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FAQ) after figuring out that .gz / GzipStream was not the way to go since its only for individual files. More importantly, doing this is similar to using [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) meaning it will create a FILE. But I have whole folder zipped. How do I unzip to a

For some reason the [example unzipping](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#-unpack-a-zip-with-full-control-over-the-operation) here is set to ignore directories, so I'm not totally sure how that is done.

Also, I need to use .NET 2.0 for accomplish this.

Comment: did you look into code samples here https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples

Comment: I did, just amended the question - it doesn't demonstrate how to deal with directories / subdirectories?

Comment: Have you checked this link? http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/6873/23543.aspx

Comment: Good find @Bijington, you should make that the answer

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think it is the easier way.
Default functionality (please look here for more info https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/FastZip)

it extract with folders.

code:

```
using System;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

var zipFileName = @"T:\Temp\Libs\SharpZipLib_0860_Bin.zip";
var targetDir = @"T:\Temp\Libs\unpack";
FastZip fastZip = new FastZip();
string fileFilter = null;

// Will always overwrite if target filenames already exist
fastZip.ExtractZip(zipFileName, targetDir, fileFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
public void UnZipp(string srcDirPath, string destDirPath)
{
        ZipInputStream zipIn = null;
        FileStream streamWriter = null;

        try
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destDirPath));

            zipIn = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(srcDirPath));
            ZipEntry entry;

            while ((entry = zipIn.GetNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(destDirPath + entry.Name);

                if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
                }

                if (!entry.IsDirectory)
                {
                    streamWriter = File.Create(destDirPath + entry.Name);
                    int size = 2048;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

                    while ((size = zipIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                    }
                }

                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException lException)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (zipIn != null)
            {
                zipIn.Close();
            }

            if (streamWriter != null)
            {
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

It's sloppy but I hope it helps!

Comment: The question asks for a solution to extract from a folder
if (!entry.IsDirectory) excludes directories