# Is there any other options to unzip file using visual studio .net 3.5?

Tags: vb.net

Hi is there any other option apart from using Shell32 to unzip file that support .net 3.5 framework? Using system.Io.compression is not supported in .net 3.5 framework

Comment: Can you provide your code?  What do you mean by 'Not Supported'?

Comment: @NathanA The System.IO.Compression class `ZipFile` is only available starting in the .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/ is an option too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unzip files programmatically in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836736/unzip-files-programmatically-in-net)

Comment: [System.Io.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.80).aspx) gos back to NET 2.0, it is only `ZipFile` which showed up in 4.5.  There are gobs of NET related zip libraries including a C# one for 7zip, your Google must be broke

Comment: http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/51254

Comment: @Inisheer I download the file but cannot open it and I'm using VS 2013. Is there a way to open it with VS 2013?

Comment: @plokuun It should be a .dll file correct? If so, just add it as a reference in your project.

Comment: What's wrong in using Shell32 ?